# Validating msg.data.length

Tags: solidity

Should I validate `msg.data.length` for methods that may change storage?

http://securify.ch/ recommends this but I can't find any mentions/explanations elsewhere.

Shouldn't this only be a problem, when I typecast values, e.g. uint8 to uint256 or so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This measure is to prevent the The **ERC20 Short Address Attack**. this attack occurs when an attacker use an incomplete address which ends with zeros 0,'00'...

if an attacked generate an address like `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa0000`. he can provide `0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa` (zeros omitted) to the transfer function This would actually cause a transfer of a value shifted by 16 bits, i.e. 65536 times larger than X, to attacker’s Ethereum account.

the `msg.data` would be like following :

```
Function: transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)

0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000000797350000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005150ac4c39a6f3f0000
```

to avoid that we have a 'malicious' msg.data we could [check](http://[https://github.com/MonolithDAO/token/blob/master/src/Token.sol#L23][1])

```
 modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint numwords) {
        assert(msg.data.length == numwords * 32 + 4);
        _;
```

to read in depth about this attack please refer to the golem [blog](https://blog.golemproject.net/how-to-find-10m-by-just-reading-blockchain-6ae9d39fcd95).

Answer (score 11):

I've to add this check can cause other type of problems.

For example if you try to interact from a multisig wallet the data is padded to 32 bytes so a valid call will endup being rejected because of extra padding bytes were not taking into account, https://blog.coinfabrik.com/smart-contract-short-address-attack-mitigation-failure/.

Also if you want to implement inheritance between methods your msg.data can be less than the size you were expecting https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/issues/261. OpenZeppelin has recently removed all the checks https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/pull/277.

So the current recommendation is **not** to use that mitigation. You should not sign a transaction without validating the input paramters.