# A couple of questions on the Short Address attack

Tags: solidity, attacks

I have a few questions on the Short Address attack:

1. Is it possible to apply this attack on a function which **does not** take encoded byte-code as input and execute it, for example - `function func(bytes data)`?
2. If yes, doesn't this mean that one should verify `msg.data.length` in **every** public or external function?
3. If a function of mine verifies the value of `msg.sender` (doesn't matter how, but let's assume that the function can determine whether or not I trust this sender) - am I still at any risk of a non-verified sender calling it with malicious data?

I have found several partially-related answers on this website (one of them to my own question), but I have not been able to decide how this attack should be handled with **in my solidity code** (off-chain code is not critical as far as I'm concerned):

1. [Answer 1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/20839/16043)
2. [Answer 2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/20842/16043)
3. [Answer 3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63281/16043)

The majority opinion seems to be that such protection **should not** be added on-chain.

In my 3 questions above, I am trying to determine whether or not I can feel safe with that.

Thank you very much!!!

**UPDATE:**

As I mentioned above (and to the reader who closed this question as duplicate by specifying a question which I have explicitly linked here):

I have found several partially-related answers on this website (one of them to my own question), but I have not been able to decide how this attack should be handled with **in my solidity code** (off-chain code is not critical as far as I'm concerned):

1. [Answer 1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/20839/16043)
2. [Answer 2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/20842/16043)
3. [Answer 3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/63281/16043)

Moreover, I have linked here both answers to the question suggested as a duplicate of mine (1 and 2 above), one of which was given by this reader (who apparently didn't bother to read through).

So again - the question (not answered anywhere within the linked material) - should I handle this attack on-chain or off-chain?

Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating msg.data.length](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/validating-msg-data-length)

Comment: @Ismael: I think you didn't bother to read through. I have linked both answers to the question which you have suggested as duplicate (one of them being yours!!!). None of them answers my specific question - should I handle the Short Address attack on-chain or off-chain?

Comment: IMHO you should consider it on a case by case basis. In some cases it is desirable for smart contracts to take some measures but for most smart contracts it doen't add more security. Also I don't remeber a public incident where short address attack was used successfully.

Comment: @Ismael: Thank you. So what I'm basically looking for is the criterion by which I can determine what case I'm at.

Comment: @Ismael: Regarding "public incident where short address attack was used successfully", I think that Parity had a security bug which allowed such attack via dynamic invocation of byte-code made in the fallback function (or maybe it was in some MultiSig contract by Parity).

Comment: The two more important bugs in Parity Multisig wallet are unrelated to short address attack: [initWallet not protected](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/on-the-parity-wallet-multisig-hack-405a8c12e8f7), [selfdestruct bug](https://www.parity.io/security-alert-2/).