# How to Transfer And TransferFrom On The Tether Smart-contract from another smart-contract? It uses onlyPayloadSize?

Tags: solidity, tokens

Hi I'm trying to call transfer and transferFrom on the Tether smart-contact token located at 0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7.

It is the only token I have a problem with transferring from within my smart-contract.

I'm guessing it's because of the use of the onlyPayloadSize modifier. If anyone understands whats going on, and how to fix this, that would be awesome.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: `onlyPayloadSize` should cause problems only if you're trying to invoke this function dynamically from another contract (i.e., via `call`).

Comment: How do you invoke `transfer` or `transferFrom`? Do you have a transaction that failed?

Comment: I am invoking the transfer and transferFrom function from within my smart-contract. So i'm using another smart-contract to invoke it.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is 2 years late.. but I ran into this exact same problem today, and it surprised me how little information I could find.

The problem is that, calling usdt.transferFrom works with an external account, but does not work when calling from within a contract.

USDT did publish its contract code : https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code

Which shows it uses the onlyPayloadSize modifier. According to another answer here: [Validating msg.data.length](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/validating-msg-data-length) and the article it references: https://blog.coinfabrik.com/smart-contract-short-address-attack-mitigation-failure/

It is possible for EVM to pad calls, causing msg.data.length to be longer than expected, thus failing the tx.

The most common solution seems to be just using Zeppelin's [SafeERC20 library](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol), like here in Aave's [LendingPoolCore.sol](https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol/blob/master/contracts/lendingpool/LendingPoolCore.sol#L431), which passes arguments to transferFrom via abi.encodeWithSelector(token.transferFrom.selector, from, to, value)

I tried it and it works perfectly. It costs a little bit more gas, my estimate is 20k-40k more, not a significant amount.