# My contract is not getting paid with TETHER. (Cannot transfer)

Tags: tokens, bsc, address.transfer, tether

I am creating a Smart contract that produces X Coins. If they send 1 USDT to the contract, I want to give 1 X Coin, which they can withdraw whenever they want.
The reason why I want to use TransferFrom is that people can leave the X Coin for interest instead of withdrawing it immediately. So I want to use the Transfer function.

When I create a smart contract in another ERC20 Standard myself, I can interact with it and run the transfer function successfully.

**PROBLEM:**
I got the Tether contract source code from https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code.

I deployed it via Remix IDE to JavaScript VM(London) with
Account 1 (0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4).
Then, my own contract, X Token,
Account 2 (0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2)
I deployed with.

I have completed the approval process
With USDT token account in account1, I confirm the address of X COIN smart contract to unlimited USDT smart contract.
However, whenever I try to perform the transfer, I get the following error.

```
revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

I'm sure the balance is enough
There are 500,000,000 coins on account1 and I just want to withdraw 1,000,000 coins.
I get this error only on USDT', not at any other contract address. What do you think is the problem?

X TOKEN SOURCE CODE:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract BEP20 {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 6;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint256 public totalMintSupply;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);
    event Mint(address indexed from, uint256 _value);
    address owner;
    address feeCollector;
    uint256 initialSupply = 500000000;
    uint256 fee;
    uint256 burnAmount;
    string tokenName = 'XTOKEN';
    string tokenSymbol = 'XXX'; 
    address acceptedToken;
    uint256 priceA;
    uint256 priceBicot;
    uint8 phasenum;
    bool flag;

    uint256 public depositAmount;
    uint256 public amountOut;
    address public usdtToken;

    
    constructor() public {
        // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);
        // Give the creator all initial tokens
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        // Set the name for display purposes
        name = tokenName;
        // Set the symbol for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;
        //Set owner of the token
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }


    function balanceOf(address _sender) public view returns(uint256 _balance){
        return balanceOf[_sender];
    }

    //I didn't care about the security measures I just tried to run the transfer
    function setDepositParams(address _usdtToken, uint256 _depositAmount, uint256 _amountOut) public {
        usdtToken = _usdtToken;
        depositAmount = _depositAmount;
        amountOut = _amountOut;
    }

    //I didn't care about the security measures I just tried to run the transfer
    function getDeposit() public {
        Callee c = Callee(usdtToken);
        bool trans;
        trans = c.transfer(owner, depositAmount);
        require(trans == true, 'Invalid payment');
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amountOut;
        balanceOf[owner] -= amountOut;
    }

    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        require(_to != address(0), 'To cannot be empty.');
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value, 'Insufficient balance.');
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }
    


}

contract Callee{
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}
```

Comment: Please include the code calling it, seems like you are including a value on the call therefore it thinks it must be payable, but it'll be impossible to know unless you add more detail

Comment: I think I found a solution to the problem. The problem may be in the Tether source code, or it has a setting that I don't understand and I'm overlooking it.

I tried to make a payment by triggering the transferFrom function with another stable coin and it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The USDT code uses a onlyPayLoadSize() modifier on it's transferFrom() function

`function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32)`

The EVM pads calls adding bytes to the msg.data.length by adding zeros, failing the transaction.

The solution is to use OpenZeppelin's SafeERC20 library's `safeTransferFrom()` function which makes a low level call to the transferFrom() function.

Import the library by adding `"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";`

And

`using SafeERC20 for ERC20;`

make the call like this:

`ERC20(tokenAddress).safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);`

Here is the reference to the original post I saw when encountering the same error [how-to-transfer-and-transferfrom-on-the-tether-smart-contract-from-another-smart](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64517/how-to-transfer-and-transferfrom-on-the-tether-smart-contract-from-another-smart)